# EntityFramework в приложении реализующем службу Windows

Tags: c#, entity-framework, service

В одном приложение размещаю две службы Windows. При первом же обращении к EntityFramework выскакивает исключение

System.InvalidOperationException не обработано пользовательским кодом
Message=Нельзя использовать контекст во время создания модели. Это         исключение может возникать, когда контекст используется в методе OnModelCreating 
  или если к одному и тому же экземпляру контекста одновременно осуществляется доступ из нескольких потоков. 
  Следует учитывать, что для членов экземпляров DbContext и связанных классов потокобезопасность не гарантируется.
  Source=EntityFramework

Вопрос: Где же надо разместить экземпляры DbContext, ведь две службы это минимум 2 потока, да и для обработки запросов к службам используются несколько Task'ов на запрос?

Спасибо.

Comment: Создавайте отдельные контексты на операцию.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Создавать контент в головном Taske обработки запроса пробовал: Выдается исключение описанное выше. Если контент создавать в головном классе службы - вылетает исключение Не могу открыть базу данных. ( с этой же строкой коннекта обычное приложение великолепно работает.)

Comment: Не надо в головном создавать. Создавайте их так, чтобы не больше 1 потока с контекстом работало.

Comment: @PavelMayorov "чтобы не больше 1 потока с контекстом работало" - это и получается в головном потоке службы (не всего приложения)

Comment: Вы же сами писали про *"используются несколько Task'ов на запрос"* и *"головной Task"*. Значит, поток у вас точно не один.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Task'ов то много, да контент определен только в одной задаче (потоке). Или Вы предлагаете сделать однопоточное приложение? Так такое в принципе, по-моему, не возможно: ведь служб то 2. Для более быстрого взаимопонимания :-) : первая служба приложения - классический Тср сервер (на TcpListener), который слушает порт и обрабатывает пришедшие данные. Контекст размещал в головном классе службы и головном классе обработчика данных.

Comment: Нет, я предлагаю создавать контекст в каждом потоке. Не в одном, не в "Головной задаче", а *в каждой задаче, где он нужен*.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Спасибо. Заработало.